# NextJS default SSR vs using express

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

Why would someone doing SSR with Next.js use Express (or other server) instead of building and initializing with the built in `next start`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Next.js team is always working on ways to eliminate the need to use a custom server.

For example: in the past, it was required for:

- static asset routing (such as `robots.txt`)
- internationalization middleware
- relay modern server
- dynamic routing

Now it's just sometimes needed for middleware. Just note you could be in an old project that made that decision based on a historical need, not necessarily one that's present anymore.

[Zeit themselves advertise multiple custom server examples](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples) (just search for "express").